# NSData型への変換について

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

```
func Sample() {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let publicKeyPath = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("public.pem")
    let privateKeyPath = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("private.pem")
    let keyPair: (publicKey: SecKey?, privateKey: SecKey?) = generateKeyPair()

    do {
        let publicData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: publicKeyPath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        let keyDef = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        keyDef.setObject(publicData, forKey: "pubKeyData")

        var pubKeyString = NSString(data: publicData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(pubKeyString!)
        let UserId = "sample-sample-sample-sample-sample"
        let dict: [String: AnyObject]? = ["user_id": userId, "public_key": pubKeyString!]

    } catch {

    }
}
```

## 何をしたいか

鍵を生成しKeyChainに保存したい。

## 実行結果

```
let publicData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: publicKeyPath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
```

の行で中に入らずcatchしてしまう。

どのように修正するときちんと動いてくれますでしょうか。

## NSError

The file “public.pem” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

エラーの通りファイルが見当たらないみたいです。
どのようにpublicKeyを該当Pathに保存できますでしょうか。

Comment: 発生している`NSError`の内容は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> エラーの通りファイルが見当たらないみたいです。
>   どのようにpublicKeyを該当Pathに保存できますでしょうか。

`~/Documents/public.pem` へ publicKey を保存する方法です。

```
func writePublicKey() {
    // 公開鍵
    let publicKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx"

    let sharedfileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if let documentDirectoryURL = sharedfileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last {
        let publicKeyFileURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("public.pem")

        do {
            // 公開鍵を `~/Documents/public.pem` へと書き込みを試みる
            try publicKey.writeToURL(publicKeyFileURL, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```